# Why 'argument is of length zero'?

Tags: r

I have list which read from text file, I want to separate this string and I found this can be done with read.table (still trying). Here I tried with 'separate' and as for now I want to know what the error argument is saying?

```
                STN.....TIME.TMP.DEW.RH..DIR.SPD.VIS..CLOUDS
1       DD/HHMM C   C   %   deg m/s km                          
2  ==== ======= === === === === === ==== ======= ======= =======
3  WMAU 02/0000  23  23 100 260   2  3.0  FEW***  BKN140  BKN270
4                                                   WMAU 01/2300
5                                                   WMAU 01/2200
6                                                   WMAU 01/2100
7                                                   WMAU 01/2000
8                                                   WMAU 01/1900
9                                                   WMAU 01/1800
10                                                  WMAU 01/1700
11                                                  WMAU 01/1600
12                                                  WMAU 01/1500
13                                                  WMAU 01/1400
14                                                  WMAU 01/1300
15                                                  WMAU 01/1200
16                                                  WMAU 01/1100
17                                                  WMAU 01/1000
18                                                  WMAU 01/0900
19 WMAU 01/0800  28  26  89  30   3 10.0  FEW020  SCT140  BKN270
20 WMAU 01/0700  27  25  89  90   3 10.0  SCT020  BKN140  BKN270
21 WMAU 01/0600  27  26  94  50   2 10.0  FEW017  SCT020  BKN140
22 WMAU 01/0500  28  26  89  90   2 10.0  FEW017  SCT020  BKN270
23 WMAU 01/0400  30  27  84  60   2 10.0  FEW017  SCT020  BKN270
24 WMAU 01/0300  30  26  79  90   2 10.0  FEW017  SCT020  BKN270
25 WMAU 01/0200  29  27  89 270   2 10.0  FEW017  SCT140  BKN270
26 WMAU 01/0100  26  25  94 260   2 10.0  FEW010  SCT140  BKN270
27 WMAU 01/0000  24  24 100 270   2  8.0  FEW***  SCT140  BKN270
```

To use 'separate', I know it can't be done with early line because it lacks of element, so I take data start from line 19.

```
datan <- read.table("C:/Users/NARC/Documents/Saleha/mersing.txt", skip = 25)

> str(datan)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ V1 : Factor w/ 1 level "WMAU": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 8 levels "01/0000","01/0100",..: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
 $ V3 : int  27 27 28 30 30 29 26 24
 $ V4 : int  25 26 26 27 26 27 25 24
 $ V5 : int  89 94 89 84 79 89 94 100
 $ V6 : int  90 50 90 60 90 270 260 270
 $ V7 : int  3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 $ V8 : num  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 8
 $ V9 : Factor w/ 4 levels "FEW***","FEW010",..: 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 1
 $ V10: Factor w/ 3 levels "BKN140","SCT020",..: 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
 $ V11: Factor w/ 2 levels "BKN140","BKN270": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2

df %>% separate (datan, c('STN','TIME', 'TMP', 'DEW', 'RH', 'DIR', 'SPD', 'VIS', 'CLOUDS'),sep = "\t")
```

Error :

```
Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: Can you add `str(datan)` in your question?

Comment: This looks like you might have fixed-width input. Look into `read.fwf()` or `readr::read_fwf()`. That should make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @MrFlick, the 'fixed-width input' issue, is it because of my coding or due to early webscrapping work or the data source/website itself?

Comment: It's due to those missing values in the first few lines of the data. R doesn't know where fields start and end if there are no values in them. Since visually they align with the right most columns, it would appear to me that the file is more fixed-width rather than delimited (but really it's a bit of both)